# Trouble with creating good IF statement in C

Tags: c, if-statement, char

I am trying to create something like that with IF condition:

```
if(mychar[i] = "+")
{
   /* do something */
}
```

I want to check If char[number i-1] is plus but i can't I define plus in my condition correctly :/

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: No offence, but if this sort of thing is troubling for you I would recommend getting a good book on C before going any further.

Answer (score 7):

Two fixes:

```
if(mychar[i] == '+')
                ^ use '' for char, and "" for strings
             ^ = is an assignment operator, == is a comparison operator
```

Worth noticing that although not recommended, using the assignment operator only as a boolean expression is valid, as 0 is considered FALSE,and any other value is considered TRUE.

Comment: Fix 'if(mychar[i] == '+')' - 'i' missing from if..  <g>
'

Comment: I know you would spot it and fix, but it was just too good an opportunity to pass up :)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this mishap of using one equals sign, just get into doing this way

```
if ('+' == mychar[i])
```

Once you are into this habit of putting the constant (char, int, double, ...) the compile will spit out your mistake.

Comment: IMO, this way is much harder to read. Better to learn the proper way of comparing values than to use a bandage.

Comment: NO! Yoda conditions are for crappy compilers that are unable to warn you about writing code much more logically. Nobody says "If plus is the `mychar[i]`".

Comment: You get into the habit and then you have no problems. It is about getting conditioned into a certain thinking. Oh - It works without fault.

Comment: Why should anyone train themselves to write code illogically when any modern compiler is able to warn about such constructs. It would be better to train yourself to read and comprehend compiler errors and warnings than write backwards code.

Comment: @dreamlax - The statement `if (mychar[i] = 'x')` is logically correct. But may not be what you intended. It is like saying 'Is 5 pence in my wallt, lets check, oh yes it is' or 'What coins are in my wallet, is there a 5 pence, yes there is' Both reasonable and logical statements.

Comment: @EdHeal: It may not be what you intended, but that's why any decent compiler will warn you to make sure.

Comment: You may get a warning, but lots of legacy code comes with lots of those. Better to code to reduce those problems. I have just learnt different and have saved myself lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

Given your original if statement `f(mychar[i]="+") { do sth }` :

First, using a single `=` causes an assignment. In this case, an assignment of "+" to `mychar[i]`.

C will let you assign a value in an if statement, but I never knew any one who did it in practice. You are trying to compare values, so you want to use `==` instead of `=`.

Second, you are using a constant string `"+"` instead of a char `'+'`, so the compiler is complaining about assigning a pointer to a character string to a character.

Finally, I use a construct when comparing a value against a constant. I put the constant before `==`.

`if('+' == mychar[1])`

If I'm typing quickly and type `if('+' = mychar[1])` I'll get a compile-time error for trying to assign a value to a constant.